# How do I use the Facebook JavaScript SDK to run a large number (67) of FQL queries?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using FQL through the Facebook JavaScript SDK to request the Like and Share counts for a number of URLs (67 in total). The URLs are nearly identical, except for a fragment identifier (a.k.a. hash string) that differentiates them.

Here's an example call to the API:

```
var queries = {
  "101": "SELECT share_count, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = \"http://www.example.com/foo/bar/#101\"",
  "102": "SELECT share_count, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = \"http://www.example.com/foo/bar/#102\"",
  "103": "SELECT share_count, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = \"http://www.example.com/foo/bar/#103\"",
  "104": "SELECT share_count, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = \"http://www.example.com/foo/bar/#104\""
};

FB.api('/fql', {
  q: queries
}, function(result) {
  console.log(result.data);
});
```

This works in modern browsers, but fails in a few older ones, namely IE/8 and FF/3.6. In those browsers, I get a JavaScript error from the Facebook JS SDK library:

> Your browser does not support long connect requests. You can fix this problem by upgrading your browser or installing the latest version of Flash

I suspect that this error has to do with the Facebook SDK's method of making large POST requests cross-domain, which would explain why older browsers can't handle it.

I can get this to work, avoiding the error, if I severely limit the number of FQL queries that I'm running at once - i.e., down from 67 to about 8. However, that's not acceptable given the requirements of my project. I could probably split the single large API request into 8-9 smaller requests, but that's not an ideal solution.

Is there a better way to retrieve the data that I need while avoiding the JS error above? I have a couple of ideas, but don't know how if they're viable or how to approach them:

- Supply the URL dynamically; that is, somehow make a single FQL request using the base URL (everything but the fragment identifier) and a function, regular expression or other representation of the possible values for the fragment identifier in the different versions of the URL. Or, I could also make use of data from all URLs known to Facebook that contain my base URL as a substring; in theory, that should return the complete set of 67 that I care about.
- Use a different method for accessing this data. Facebook supports [batch requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/), and mentions that they're appropriate to use for querying large amounts of data. However, they seem to require an authentication token in all cases, which I won't have (it's a requirement for my project to not require authentication, and I'm only trying to access public data anyway), and I can't find a coherent example of using them in JavaScript, so I can't determine how to format my code.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or input. Code example would be much appreciated as well, as I'm having a hard time grokking Facebook's documentation, and most of its code examples are for languages other than JavaScript.

Thanks!